# black lines around image using warpPerspective for stitching in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

Im trying to build a mosaic panorama from a video.
I stitched every frame together, but there is a problem in the final image.
I used **findHomography** for translation matrix, **mask** , **warpPerspective** and copy the new warped image into the final image panorama.

I think this is a problem of warpPerspective.Does anybody know a solution how to fix these black lines?

these black vertical lines are the corners of the stitched image.How to remove them?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.I figured out the corners of the stitched image and I tried to manually edit the mask.I draw some the black lines using this code to mask:

```
            line(mask, corner_trans[0], corner_trans[2], CV_RGB(0, 0, 0), 4, 8);
            line(mask, corner_trans[2], corner_trans[3], CV_RGB(0, 0, 0), 4, 8);
            line(mask, corner_trans[3], corner_trans[1], CV_RGB(0, 0, 0), 4, 8);
            line(mask, corner_trans[1], corner_trans[0], CV_RGB(0, 0, 0), 4, 8);
```